# Using variables from two different size datasets (and logic relations) to create a new variable

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. The number of observations is very different, and I would like to use some information from one dataframe into the other, conditioning to some logical relations, and I can't seem to be able to. A down-scaled example would look something like this:

```
year <- as.vector(c(rep(1949,5), rep(1950,5), rep(1951,5), rep(1952,5)))
moneyband <- as.vector(c(rep(c(10,20,30,40,50),4)))
rate <-as.vector(c(rep(c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),2),rep(c(0.15,0.25,0.35,0.45,0.55),2)))

datasmall <- as.data.frame(cbind(year,moneyband,rate))

yearbig <- as.vector(c(rep(1949,10), rep(1950,10), rep(1951,10), rep(1952,11)))
earnings <- as.vector(c(rep(c(9,19,30,39,50),8),60))

databig <- as.data.frame(cbind(yearbig,earnings))
```

Now I want to create a new variable in the big database (let's call it ratebig) that assigns to that variable the rate associated with that amount of earnings, if earnings (in the big database) equal moneyband (in the small database) for a given year. As you can see, in this example this would happen with the values 30 and 50. The rest I would like them to be NA.

I tried this:

```
databig$ratebig <- NA
for (i in 1949:1952) {
  databig$ratebig[datasmall$year == i & (databig$earnings[databig$yearbig==i]==datasmall$moneyband[datasmall$year == i])] <- datasmall$rate[datasmall$year == i & (databig$earnings[databig$yearbig==i]==datasmall$moneyband[datasmall$year == i])]
}
```

But the different size of databases (or other things) are giving me trouble (it gives me errors and the results are wrong). It seems the result does not take care the conditions as I would like, and it is influenced by relative position and the structure in the two datasets.
In principle, I wouldn't want to merge the datasets (we are talking about a high number of observations in the real data) and was hoping for a way to do this.
Thanks!!

Comment: but `merge` seems to work for your case, `merge(databig, datasmall, by.x = c("yearbig", "earnings"), 
      by.y = c("year", "moneyband"), all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: @Ronak Thanks! Maybe you're right and I was getting too confused... it does indeed work. I still wonder why my syntax is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case `merge` works fine

```
merge(databig, datasmall, by.x = c("yearbig", "earnings"), 
                          by.y = c("year", "moneyband"), all.x = TRUE)

#   yearbig earnings rate
#1     1949        9   NA
#2     1949        9   NA
#3     1949       19   NA
#4     1949       19   NA
#5     1949       30 0.30
#6     1949       30 0.30
#7     1949       39   NA
#8     1949       39   NA
#9     1949       50 0.50
#10    1949       50 0.50
#.....
```

Regarding why your `for` loop doesn't work as expected you need to do it for every row of `databig`

```
databig$ratebig <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(databig)) {
   inds <- databig$yearbig[i] == datasmall$year & 
           databig$earnings[i] == datasmall$moneyband
   if (any(inds))
    databig$ratebig[i] <- datasmall$rate[inds]  
}
```